# Which type to declare with this signature?

Tags: c, declaration, typing

I am new to C, and I have the following C function :

```
typedef unsigned short  (API_ENTRY _DLL_PTR T_Lec_Dictionnaire)
                                    (   IN      unsigned char FARPTR    pcChemin,
                                        IN      short                   sNoTable,
                                        IN      char                    tcCode[9],
                                        IN      char                    tcPeriode[50],
                                        OUT     char FARPTR             szLibelle,
                                        IN_OUT  short FARPTR            psLgLibelle,
                                        OUT     unsigned short FARPTR   pusCodeErreur);
```

And I have a problem with the szLibelle variable : I can't figure out which type to declare, and how to use it.

I tried

```
char libelle[] = "";
char * szLibelle = &libelle;
```

but the function return me the error code 54 which means "The value of the parameter misfits".

According to the "sz" prefix it seems that my declaration is incorrect, but I can't figure out why ...
The documentation says, for this parameter : "Memory zone containing the characters passed by address" (sorry, translating broughly from french ...).

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: `FARPTR` is very old Windows/x86. It means just a pointer, in this case to one or more chars (a string), so `char szLibelle[N]` will do.

Comment: The variable `OUT char FARPTR szLibelle` is declared as to be returned or modified by the function, but your declaration `char libelle[] = "";` will create a **constant** null array that should conflict with definition. Depending on the function behavior, it could require an array on N elements, as @PaulOgilvie said, or simply a ponter if the string is returned in a malloced memory.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer. Could you tell me what N represents (maybe it's just an example) ? In fact, the library is an "old" one which permits one to read French Heathcare Professionals Cards, that's why. And the doc is originally in french like the library.

Comment: thanks @Frankie_C, so, let's assume the string would be 32-char long. How would I make my declaration in each case  ?  Sorry for the question, but it's quite a pain in the ... to understand.

Comment: @Frankie_C, the string cannot be returned as a malloced string as a parameter because it is not a double pointer (it can be returned as function return, but then the parameter is not needed).

Comment: As @PaulOgilvie said `char szLibelle[N]`, where N=32 + 1 for zero ending: `char szLibelle[33]`

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try it and give you the results. :)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes you're right, I missed the point.

Comment: It seems that it does not do the trick : the function still return errcode 54

Answer (score 0):

You declration was 100% right ! But the fact is that the manner the 5th parameter is treated depends on the value of the INOUT psLgLibelle.

The doc is clear as mud about it .....

Once more, thanks for your help guys !